# How to view the file difference?

Tags: file, directory

I'm having two versions of PHP scripts. I forgot which lines I modified in the new version.

I have more than 100 files. So can anyone tell me how to bulk view the difference by comparing two directories?

Thanks

PS: If you guys know any free or paid tool please let me know.

Comment: you shout start looking into git. http://git-scm.com/

Comment: You should definitely be using a revision-control system, such as Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unix/Mac environments:

```
diff -rq dirA dirB
```

There are plenty of command-line and GUI tools for Windows as well. Also consider using any [vcs](/questions/tagged/vcs), modern [dvcs](/questions/tagged/dvcs) systems like [git](/questions/tagged/git) and [mercurial](/questions/tagged/mercurial) are very well suited even for a single developer.

## See also:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/79226/different-files-of-two-directories

Answer (score 1):

One of the best paid tools : Beyond Compare 3  http://www.scootersoftware.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could combine a simple shell-script loop with the `diff` command... but yes, as Andreas AL mentioned, source control is a more robust solution to your problem.